# PHP Ajax Form Integration return arrays

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Using PHP and jQuery Ajax to build a basic log in system.

What I want to do is submit sections of a form via ajax and return an array. I'm not quite sure if I've got this one right.

Here is the PHP

```
if($access_function == 'access_login_1'){
    $email = $_POST['access_email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['access_pwd'];

    if(!$email || !$pwd){
        $error = 'Empty';
    }
    else {
        $user = get_user($email);
        if($user && $user['pwd'] == $pwd){
            if($user['status'] == 1){
                $action = 1;
            }
            else {
                $order = 'Unauthorised';
            }
        }
        else {
            $error = 'invalid';
        }
    }
    return array('action'=>$action,'error'=>$error,'order'=>$order);
}
```

The get_user function is like this::

```
function get_user($email){
    global $cnx;
    $q = $cnx->prepare("SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE email = :email");
    $q->execute(array(':email' => $email)); 
    return $q->fetch();
}
```

Now the jQuery is the real struggle. What I want is to submit the serialised values to this php. If the script returns an action of 1, I want to perform another script, I want $error to go into a div called error and order into a div called $order

This hasn't worked:

```
function sendvars(container,linkrul,perform){
    var vars = 'access=1';
    $(container).find('input').each(function(){
        vars += '&' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).val();
    });
    $.ajax({type:'POST',url:linkrul,data:vars,success:function(results){
        if(results == 1){  }
        else { $(container).find('.orders').html(results).slideDown(300); }
        }
    });
}
```

-- Hashing is off for not just while we test everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think more carefully about what data is being sent from the PHP to the AJAX callback:

1. Remember that a PHP script cannot "return" anything, it simply "displays" it. So `return array('action'=>$action,'error'=>$error,'order'=>$order);` will not produce any output that the Javascript can read unless you then serialize it (turn it into a string and output it) in some way, such as XML or JSON (using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode)). You can test that the script is outputting something useful by looking at it directly in your browser, or using debug tools such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).
2. jQuery needs to know what encoding you've output your data in (see [documentation on the `dataType` parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). If it's XML, it will pass the whole XML document to your callback function, so you would need to use functions like `.find` and `.each` to inspect it. Probably the easiest is for your PHP to use `header('Content-type: application/json');` (which tells jQuery you're using JSON) and echo some data using `json_encode`, so that your Javascript callback gets a simple Javascript object to work with.
3. Your current Javascript assumes that the result of the AJAX call is either an integer (`result == 1`) or  a blob of HTML `.html(results)`. A better approach would be to pass back the whole result structure shown in your PHP code (i.e. `echo json_encode(array('action'=>$action,'error'=>$error,'order'=>$order));`). Then you can check and act on each part of the structure separately (e.g. `response.action == 1`, `.html(response.order)`), and your code becomes more readable and more flexible for future situations.

Finally, jQuery has some built-in functions which can do some more of your work for you here: check out [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) as a short-hand for the AJAX call, and [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) (or its cousin [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)) for reading out the current values of form elements in a form you can send to the AJAX callback.

(Incidentally, I'm sure you'd have spotted this, but I presume `linkrul` should be `linkurl`)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it returning json encoded arrays:

```
if($access_function == 'access_login_1'){
    $email = $_POST['access_email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['access_pwd'];

    if(!$email || !$pwd){
        $resp = array(
           'action' => $someValue,
           'order' => $someValue,
           'error' => 'No Email or password provided' 
         );
    }
    else {
        $user = get_user($email);
        if($user && $user['pwd'] == $pwd){
            if($user['status'] == 1){
                $resp = array(
                   'action' => 1,
                   'order' => $someValue,
                   'error' => 'No Error' 
                );
            }
            else{
                $resp = array(
                    'action' => $someValue,
                    'order' => 'Unauthorised',
                    'error' => 'Order Error'
                );
            }
        }
        else {
               $resp = array(
                    'action' => $someValue,
                    'order' => 'Unauthorised',
                    'error' => 'Invalid'
                );
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($resp);
}
```

And in js:

```
function sendvars(container,linkrul,perform){
    var vars = 'access=1';
    $(container).find('input').each(function(){
        vars += '&' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).val();
    });
    $.ajax({type:'POST',url:linkrul,data:vars,dataType:'JSON',success:function(results){
         if(results.action == 1){ 
            //do something 
         }else if(results.action == someOtherValue){
           $(container).find('.orders').html(results.order).slideDown(300);
         }else{
            alert(results.error); //Or put the error in some div
         }    
        //any other code or if/else statement
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also one option.

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' class='email' />
<input type='password' class='pass' />
```

**PHP - checkLogin.php**

```
<?php

$action = 0;
$order  = 0;
$error  = 0;

if(isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['pass'])) {
     if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
          $user = get_user($email);
          if($user && $user['pwd'] == $_POST['pass']){
               if($user['status'] == 1){
                    $action = 1;
               } else {
                    $order = 'Unauthorised';
               }
          } else {
            $error = 'invalid';
          }
     } else {
          $error = "Empty";
     }

     $array = array('action'=>$action,'error'=>$error,'order'=>$order);
     echo json_encode($array);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function checkLogin(){
    var email = $('.email').val();
    var pass  = $('.pass').val();
    $.post('checkLogin.php', {email:email,pass:pass}, function(response) {
         var result = $.parseJSON(response);
         if(response['action'] == 1) {
              //authorized
         } else if(response['order'] == 'Unauthorised') {
              //unauthorized
         } else {
              //error
         }
    });
}
```